# Extract 2D outline from delaunay triangulation in CGAL

Tags: cgal

I'm able to get the delaunay triangulation from CGAL using the following [example code](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html)
How can I extract the polygonal outline (ie, the boundary edges, which can be non-convex) that forms the edges of this 2D triangulation?

Comment: Define "outline"... An alpha-shape maybe?

Comment: No, not alpha shape I think. I'm not sure how else to explain it. Boundary edges are the edges that form the outline (edges associated with only one triangle I believe).

Comment: You seem to be describing the convex hull...

Comment: No, I'm not. Draw an arbitary shape, that can be the outline of the mesh. Doesn't have to do anything with convexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [is_constraint(edge)](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title32) or the Constraint iterator.

Comment: Can you be more specific and detailed (a code sample) as to how to make use of this iterator to extract the boundary?